# Sending the unique phone id as an email

Tags: windows-phone-7

I try to create an app that allows the user to register himself for my service.
The problem is that it is very important that i can limit each user to a very single account
i figured out I could probably do this with the Phone unique id and the windows live id
i also figured out how to get These within the app , but now my problem is how to get them to me!
Can anyone help me on how to send the phone id with the desired username to my email address ?
Thank you

**EDIT**

I use this code to get the needed values

```
public static class ExtendedPropertyHelper  
{  
    private static readonly int ANIDLength = 32;  
    private static readonly int ANIDOffset = 2;  
    public static string GetManufacturer()  
    {  
        string result = string.Empty;  
        object manufacturer;  
        if (DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceManufacturer", out manufacturer))  
            result = manufacturer.ToString();  

        return result;  
    }  

    //Note: to get a result requires ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE  
    // to be added to the capabilities of the WMAppManifest  
    // this will then warn users in marketplace  
    public static byte[] GetDeviceUniqueID()  
    {  
        byte[] result = null;  
        object uniqueId;  
        if (DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueId))  
            result = (byte[])uniqueId;  

        return result;  
    }  

    // NOTE: to get a result requires ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER  
    //  to be added to the capabilities of the WMAppManifest  
    // this will then warn users in marketplace  
    public static string GetWindowsLiveAnonymousID()  
    {  
        string result = string.Empty;  
        object anid;  
        if (UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID", out anid))  
        {  
            if (anid != null && anid.ToString().Length >= (ANIDLength + ANIDOffset))  
            {  
                result = anid.ToString().Substring(ANIDOffset, ANIDLength);  
            }  
        }  

        return result;  
    }  
}
```

Now i need to store thes in variables ( what i cant really get to work ) and then send them to my php script which extracts them

in addition to this i need to ask the user to enter his email address and include this in the POST too ,
can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `DeviceExtendedProperties.DeviceUniqueId`  from `Microsoft.Phone.Info` namespace.
Don't forget to declare in `WMAppManifest.xml`

like this:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Link to msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.92%29)

Then, you can send this id to your e-mail:

```
var emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask
{
    To = "your-email@domiain.com",
    Subject = "Test Message using EmailComposeTask",
    Body = deviceId
};
emailComposeTask.Show();
```

But this will open an-email client, and I don't thik that user will be so kind to send you an email. So, you'd better send a POST request to your server

```
     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //collect all data you need:
        var deviceId = Convert.ToBase64String(ExtendedPropertyHelper.GetDeviceUniqueID());
        var userName = ExtendedPropertyHelper.GetWindowsLiveAnonymousID();
        var manufatcurer = ExtendedPropertyHelper.GetManufacturer();
        //create request string
        //[see the explanation on MSDN][2]
        var requestUrl = string
  .Format("http://myPageUrlAddress.com/script.aspx?deviceid={0}&user={1}&manufacturer={2}",
   deviceId, userName, manufatcurer);


        System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri(requestUrl);
        //create a request instance
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //and it will be sent. 
        //Also you need to create GetRequestStreamCallback method to 
        //handle server responce.
        myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new
        AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }
    //this method is empty. You can show tha dialog box about successful sending.
    public void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult result) { ; }
```

What about e-mail - just create a TextBox on the same Page, and save user input to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If "my service" is a web service, then you could use the web service instead of the mail system.

In either case you can use Convert.ToBase64String(phoneId) to convert the phone id to a string.

To send strings via mail from WP7 you need to use EmailComposeTask.